# condition to input value always return false (RUBY)

Tags: ruby

I wonder why even though I type "y" the condition will always false

```
puts "Would you like to continue [y/n]"
confirm = gets
puts confirm == "y" # why this is not true even I type "y"    

if confirm == "y"
    puts "Input is y"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `confirm = gets.chomp` cause `gets` set what you enter with `\n` in the end

```
> a = gets
> y
 => "y\n"
```

Comment: Amazing it solve it. Thank you, I'll just mark it answer after 9 mins

Answer (score 1):

Try this code instead.

```
puts "Would you like to continue [y/n]"
confirm = gets
puts "|#{confirm}|" # y\n
puts confirm.strip == "y" # gives you true
puts confirm == "y" # gives you false

if confirm == "y"
    puts "Input is y"
end
```

You could use `gets.strip` or `gets.chomp` to remove any unnecessarily characters from `gets`